# The fastest way to compare a partial string?

Tags: delphi, string, comparison, delphi-2009

I have to compare a partial string  "SKILL_______EU_______WAND_______CLERIC_______BASE_____01" with "SKILL".It's meant to check if the first four characters are "SKILL".**or the first character only,optimization is needed here**!

My problems:

1. I don't know how to do an optimized comparison.
2. It has to be repeated 35 000 times so it must be something **very**
   fast.

Thanks!

Comment: How can the first 4 characters be 'SKILL'?!

Comment: Are you trying to peraphrase my question?

Comment: Lol! No, I am not trying to paraphrase you question. I am simply pointing out that the first four characters of this string will never, ever be 'SKILL'.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use StrUtils.AnsiStartsStr for case-sensitive, StrUtils.AnsiStartsText for case-insensitive
 (add StrUtils to your uses clause)

Answer (score 5):

35000 repetitions really isn't that much these days, it probably doesn't matter what you do.

Comment: It is a sensible thought.  Do it in the most foolproof way, no matter how slow, then store the results and never do it again.

Comment: Sensible as it may be, it doesn't actually answer the question, whatever the question really is. So I could certainly understand this being voted down.

Answer (score 5):

If you really want the best speed you will have to write a little StartsWith function yourself.

```
// untested, case-sensitive
Function StartsWith(const find, text : string) : Boolean;
var i, len : integer;
begin
   result := true;
   len := Min(Length(find), Length(text));
   For i := 1 to len do
   Begin
     if (find[i] <> text[i]) 
     then begin
       result := False;
       break;
     end;
   End;   
end;
```

Comment: Delphi already has a AnsiStartsStr (case-sensitive) /AnsiStartsText (case-insensitive) function. There is no need to reimplement it. Just use the "StrUtils" unit.

Comment: @Andreas, you are right, I just couldn't find it. Just wish the full Delphi docs were online...  I'm leaving the answer, it could be a starter for a custom version.

Answer (score 2):

No matter which solution you choose please keep in mind to actually test and **benchmark** it against your current implementation.

Otherwise you are just guessing, not optimizing.

And be aware that [premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimization_%28computer_science%29#When_to_optimize).

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I think the Delphi routines are quite optimized and fast, so just use them.

```
var
  position : Integer;

begin
  // AnsiPos
  //   returns the position of a substring in a string
  //   or 0 if the substring isn't found
  position := AnsiPos('SKILL', 'SKILL_______EU_______WAND_______CLERIC_______BASE_____01');
end;
```

Comment: This will keep on scanning the entire domainstring, even if the 1st chars are unequal.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to check just the 1st character, you can do it like this:

```
if 'S' = 'SKILL_______EU_______WAND_______CLERIC_______BASE_____01'[1] then
begin
    showmessage('SKILL');
end
```

Comment: of course it compiles. I didn't tested in Delphi 2009, though. I'm sure it'll compile on all Delphi versions.

Comment: I didn't think it was legal to apply the bracket operator to a string literal. But if you say it compiles, I'll take your word for it. Note that Free Pascal *doesn't* accept that syntax (even in "Delphi mode").

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Delphi, but I think (in any language / framework / platform) Regex is the fastest way for string scanning ...

You didn't exactly specify all the conditions you are searching for...

Comment: Regex are very complete, but they are not reputed to be fast at all. You should use regex for complex searches not trivial ones, especially not if speed is of the essence.

Comment: "not reputed to be fast at all" - do you have a link for that? Most reg-ex are matched in O(n) and very hard to beat with handwritten code.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: sorry I should have been more specific; fast in case such as the one in this question. If all you want is to check the first 4-5 characters of a string to see if it matches something, you better use functions which are specifically designed and optimized for this.

Comment: That's why I said that he didn't specify all the conditions!

Answer (score 0):

Why not do:

```
function StartsWith( const AMatchStr, ATestStr : string ) : boolean;
begin
  Result := SameText( AMatchStr, copy( ATestStr, 1, Length( AMatchStr ));
end;
```

This will not process any part of ATestStr beyond your starting text.
Bri

Comment: But it will copy chars, not strictly necessary.

Comment: Why not do that? Because the library already comes with such a function, and even if it didn't, it would be better to use `StrLComp` than to make a temporary copy of the string.

Answer (score 0):

If you just what to check the first 4/5 characters you could do

```
i:= Length('SKILL');

LeftStr('SKILL_______EU_______WAND_______CLERIC_______BASE_____01',i) = 'SKILL'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if AnsiPos('SKILL', 'SKILL_______EU_______WAND_______CLERIC_______BASE_____01') > 0 then
```

I think that this should do the job, I don't know about the speed of AnsiPos, if its fast or slow or whatever. It works for me whenever I wanna compare pieces of a string. **AnsiPos()** returns an integer value which represents the start index of the string that you're looking for.